# How Can I Detect Gaps and Consecutive Periods In A Time Series In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe that is indexed by Date.  I would like to select all consecutive gaps by period and all consecutive days by Period.    How can I do this?

**Example of Dataframe with No Columns but a Date Index:**

```
In [29]: import pandas as pd

In [30]: dates = pd.to_datetime(['2016-09-19 10:23:03', '2016-08-03 10:53:39','2016-09-05 11:11:30', '2016-09-05 11:10:46','2016-09-05 10:53:39'])

In [31]: ts = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
```

As you can see there is a *gap from 2016-08-03 and 2016-09-19*.  How do I detect these so I can create descriptive statistics, i.e.  40 gaps, with median gap duration of "x", etc.  Also, I can see that *2016-09-05 and 2016-09-06 is a two day range*.  How I can detect these and also print descriptive stats?

Ideally the result would be returned as another Dataframe in each case since I want use other columns in the Dataframe to groupby.

Comment: Can you add some sample of data ? Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Sure, will add right now.

Answer (score 17):

Pandas version 1.0.1 has a built-in method [`DataFrame.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) which you can use to accomplish this. One benefit is you can use pandas series functions like `mean()` to quickly compute summary statistics on the `gaps` series object

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

# Construct dummy dataframe
dates = pd.to_datetime([
    '2016-08-03',
    '2016-08-04',
    '2016-08-05',
    '2016-08-17',
    '2016-09-05',
    '2016-09-06',
    '2016-09-07',
    '2016-09-19'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['date'])

# Take the diff of the first column (drop 1st row since it's undefined)
deltas = df['date'].diff()[1:]

# Filter diffs (here days > 1, but could be seconds, hours, etc)
gaps = deltas[deltas > timedelta(days=1)]

# Print results
print(f'{len(gaps)} gaps with average gap duration: {gaps.mean()}')
for i, g in gaps.iteritems():
    gap_start = df['date'][i - 1]
    print(f'Start: {datetime.strftime(gap_start, "%Y-%m-%d")} | '
          f'Duration: {str(g.to_pytimedelta())}')
```

Comment: If I used the column 'date'  as the index in the df, how could the deltas be estimated? The function pd.index.difference() does sth different.

Answer (score 6):

here's something to get started:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(5),columns = ['ones'])
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-09-19 10:23:03', '2016-08-03 10:53:39', '2016-09-05 11:11:30', '2016-09-05 11:10:46', '2016-09-06 10:53:39'])
daily_rng = pd.date_range('2016-08-03 00:00:00', periods=48, freq='D')
daily_rng = daily_rng.append(df.index)
daily_rng = sorted(daily_rng)
df =  df.reindex(daily_rng).fillna(0)
df = df.astype(int)
df['ones'] = df.cumsum()
```

The cumsum() creates a grouping variable on 'ones' partitioning your data at the points your provided. If you print df to say a spreadsheet it will make sense:

```
print df.head()

                     ones
2016-08-03 00:00:00     0
2016-08-03 10:53:39     1
2016-08-04 00:00:00     1
2016-08-05 00:00:00     1
2016-08-06 00:00:00     1

print df.tail()
                     ones
2016-09-16 00:00:00     4
2016-09-17 00:00:00     4
2016-09-18 00:00:00     4
2016-09-19 00:00:00     4
2016-09-19 10:23:03     5
```

now to complete:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.groupby(['ones']).aggregate({'ones':{'gaps':'count'},'index':{'first_spotted':'min'}})
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

which gives:

```
              first_time  gaps
ones                          
0    2016-08-03 00:00:00     1
1    2016-08-03 10:53:39    34
2    2016-09-05 11:10:46     1
3    2016-09-05 11:11:30     2
4    2016-09-06 10:53:39    14
5    2016-09-19 10:23:03     1
```

Comment: this looks like it is off to a good start.  I got lost after cumsum though.  At this point: `In [11]: df = df.astype(int) In [12]: df.head()
    Out[12]: 
                     ones
2016-08-03 00:00:00     0
2016-08-03 10:53:39     1
2016-08-04 00:00:00     0
2016-08-05 00:00:00     0
2016-08-06 00:00:00     0`

Comment: The key step is to get a grouping variable, that is what the cumsum is for.

Comment: Can you explain how I would take that grouping variable and detect first gap and first consecutive streak?

Comment: Has the solution so far shown the gaps properly? We can solve the consecutive streaks later.

Comment: almost can you label the gaps, "gaps" and then I will give you the answer.

Comment: is the answer ok?

Comment: I am new to answering questions on stackoverflow so apologies about how slow I am.  The gaps are labeled, but I don't understand the time dimension.  I would expect it too look more like this:    

 2016-08-03 10:53:39    0
2016-09-05 11:10:46    32

i.e. 32 days (off the top of my head), between 8/03 - 09/05  and then potentially another column like this:

              first_time  streaks
ones                          
0    2016-08-03 00:00:00     0
1    2016-08-03 10:53:39    1

As in each additional day adds to streak..

Comment: best to place your desired output into your question in a formatted style datatable. I think there are 2 effects you are trying to achieve, let's square away each in turn, first the gaps and then the specifics about 2 day ranges.