# Getting a count of missing timestamps in a dataset based on expected interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, gaps-in-data

I have a dataset that is made up of timestamp readings for pressure that should be recorded and returned every 15 minutes. The example data below shows that there are gaps greater than 15 minutes in the data set

I have been trying to find a way to add in a count column that counts how many readings are missing between received ones, such that a 15-minute interval = 0 (missed readings), a half-hour gap = 1 (missed reading )and a 45-minute gap = 2, etc.

At this stage I don't have any code that I would want to show because I am still a long way off, although I have been working around this post, but still not succeeding. [How Can I Detect Gaps and Consecutive Periods In A Time Series In Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118037/how-can-i-detect-gaps-and-consecutive-periods-in-a-time-series-in-pandas)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

```css
Place             date       pressure (m)
Somewhere   01/09/2019 00:00    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 00:30    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 00:45    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 01:15    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 01:30    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 02:15    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 02:30    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 02:45    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 03:15    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 03:30    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 03:45    34.5
Somewhere   01/09/2019 04:00    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 04:15    34
Somewhere   01/09/2019 06:45    33.5
Somewhere   01/09/2019 07:00    33.5
Somewhere   01/09/2019 07:30    34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `date` column into pandas datetime series, then use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to calculate the successive differences between the dates, then divide this differences by [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) with interval of `15min`, finally use `.fillna` to fill the `NaN` values with `0`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['gap'] = (df['date'].diff() / pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)).sub(1).fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

        Place                date  pressure (m)  gap
0   Somewhere 2019-01-09 00:00:00          34.0  0.0
1   Somewhere 2019-01-09 00:30:00          34.0  1.0
2   Somewhere 2019-01-09 00:45:00          34.0  0.0
3   Somewhere 2019-01-09 01:15:00          34.0  1.0
4   Somewhere 2019-01-09 01:30:00          34.0  0.0
5   Somewhere 2019-01-09 02:15:00          34.0  2.0
6   Somewhere 2019-01-09 02:30:00          34.0  0.0
7   Somewhere 2019-01-09 02:45:00          34.0  0.0
8   Somewhere 2019-01-09 03:15:00          34.0  1.0
9   Somewhere 2019-01-09 03:30:00          34.0  0.0
10  Somewhere 2019-01-09 03:45:00          34.5  0.0
11  Somewhere 2019-01-09 04:00:00          34.0  0.0
12  Somewhere 2019-01-09 04:15:00          34.0  0.0
13  Somewhere 2019-01-09 06:45:00          33.5  9.0
14  Somewhere 2019-01-09 07:00:00          33.5  0.0
15  Somewhere 2019-01-09 07:30:00          34.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this Shubham. It does the job perfectly. Can I just ask what the .sub(1) does. Does that look at the previous row?

Comment: `.sub(1)` subtracts `1` from the result, for example `(00:30::00 - 00:00:00) / 00:15:00 = 2`,  so we subtract 1 for adjustment in the gap.